# Google charts - calendar - stretch to full width

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Using `google.visualization.Calendar()`, how can I stretch calendar to full width of parent element? I have tried:

```
var options = {
    tooltip: { isHtml: false },
    height = 200
    //width : 1150 //This setting do not work
    //chartArea: { width: 1150} //This setting also do not work
    //chartArea: { width: "100%"} //This setting also do not work
    }
```

Comment: not possible with standard config options, you can only make it smaller using the `width` option, but this just cuts off the calendar, it does not scale...

Comment: @WhiteHat I was hoping you'll notice this question. Thank you for answer. Do you think there is some way to hack it?

Comment: I looked into that, it wouldn't be easy, because you would have to manually change every element that makes up the chart. If you notice in the browser's element inspector, the SVG element actually stretches to the requested width. But the actual chart elements do not, not good google!